# In $l_2^2$, for any two linearly independent extreme points of unit ball $x_p, x_q$, $\|ax_p+bx_q\|= 1\implies |a|\leq 1, |b|\leq 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, geometry, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I was studying about the extreme points of unit ball of a Banach space. I have a confusion in the following viewpoint:

Is it true that for any two linearly independent extreme points $x_p, x_q$ of the unit ball of $l_2^2$, $\|ax_p+bx_q\|= 1\implies |a|\leq 1, |b|\leq 1? $

I think it is true because for any parallelogram inside a unit circle, the length of the diagonal connecting to the origin will be $1$ only when each of the corresponding two sides connecting to the origin are of length less than or equal to $1$. Is my thinking true? If anyone can explain it mathematically it will be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No just take the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $a=1$, $x_q\approx -x_p$.

Comment: @Michael it is given that $x_p, x_q$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Yes, it is easy to make $x_p$ and $x_q$ linearly independent and $x_q\approx -x_p$. For example take $x_p=(1,0)$ and $x_q=(-1+\epsilon, \delta)$, where $\epsilon$ is a very small positive number and $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon(2-\epsilon)}$. Using $a=1$, if $||x_p+bx_q||=1$ then (assuming $b\neq 0$) we get  $b\approx 2$.

Comment: In general, any two nonzero vectors can be made linearly independent by adding an arbitrarily small perturbation to one of the vectors. So the assumption on linear independence is not very stringent. It would be different of you assumed orthogonality.

Comment: If you are concerned that my example vectors $x_p, x_q$ are in $\mathbb{R}^2$ then make them infinite dimensional by appending an infinite number of zeros to both of them.  But the main intuition is by drawing a picture in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $x_p$ is on the unit circle and $x_q$ is a near-antipodal point on that circle. You can "see" that if $x_p+bx_q$ is also on the circle then either $b=0$ or $b\approx 2$. The math is worked about by $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ in my previous comment.

Comment: @Michael thank you very much for the detailed clarification and sharing your valuable idea. Now, I got it very clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer summarizes my comments on $x_p\approx -x_q$.  Fix $\epsilon$ such that $0<\epsilon\leq 1/100$. Define
\begin{align*}
x_p &= (1,0,0,0,...)\\
x_q &= (-1+\epsilon, \delta, 0, 0, ...) 
\end{align*}
where $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon(2-\epsilon)}$. Then $||x_p||=||x_q||=1$. Using $a=1$ we search for $b\neq 0$ such that
$$||x_p+bx_q||=1$$
Equivalently
\begin{align*}
(1-b(1-\epsilon))^2 + b^2\delta^2 = 1
\end{align*}
$$-2b(1-\epsilon) + b^2(1-\epsilon)^2 + b^2\delta^2=0$$
Since $b\neq 0$ we factor it out to obtain
$$ -2(1-\epsilon) + b(1-\epsilon)^2 + b\delta^2 = 0$$
so
$$ \boxed{b = \frac{2(1-\epsilon)}{(1-\epsilon)^2 + \delta^2}}$$
For $\epsilon\approx 0$ we get $\delta \approx 0$ and $b \approx 2$. For $\epsilon = 1/100$ we get $b=1.98$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be an extreme point with $x_1=0$ and let $y=\alpha x+\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}e_1$ with some $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Then
$||y||=1$, and $||x-\frac{1}{\alpha}y||=\frac{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{\alpha}$. Taking $\alpha$ sufficiently large (larger than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ to be precise) this can be made less than 1, so we have a counterexample.